# How can I adjust the font size when I press the key?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel, keyevent

There's a letter "Hello world" in the center. If you press the keyboard "+" on this letter, the size increases by 2, and if you press "-", the size decreases by 2. But the font size should always be between 10 and 50 points. At first, it was 16 points.

I'm solving this problem.

The font size is only 2 increase and 2 decrease.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class T_1_2 extends JFrame {

 private int fontSize = 16;    // 글자 크기
 private JLabel lb;

 T_1_2() {
        setTitle("My Frame");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(lb=new JLabel("Hello, World!"),
                BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lb.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER); //라벨 가운데 정렬
        setFont();

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { //keylistener 클래스를 이미 구현

         @Override // 특정 동작이 일어나게 하려면 override해서 사용 
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                 lb.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize+2));
             }
             else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                 lb.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize-2));
             }
         }
        });
        setVisible(true);
 }

 private void setFont() {
        lb.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        new T_1_2();
 }
}
```

**Output**

The font size is only 2 increase and 2 decrease.

**Expected**

When a letter is vk_up, the letter becomes 2 points larger, and when a letter is vk_down, the letter becomes 2 points smaller.

It should be only 10 to 50 points, and the letters should start with 16 points when running.

Comment: `Math.min(50, fontSize + 2)`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually update the fontSize variable. In fact, the fontSize will always be 16. What you need to do is change the value of fontSize and then use your setFont() method, which will happen in your keyListener:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            if(fontSize < 50)
                fontSize += 2; //change value of fontSize by adding 2
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            if(fontSize > 10)
                fontSize -= 2;
        }
        setFont(); //use your setFont() method to set the label font with the new font size
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! it was simpler than i thought